# CloudFormation: Replace BasePathMapping with ApiMapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

I've used a CloudFormation stack inside Terraform, since WebSocket API Gateway was not supported at the time.

Recently when trying to apply changes, I've been greeted with this error:

> Mixing of REST APIs and HTTP APIs on the same domain name can only be accomplished through API Gateway's V2 DomainName interface. Currently, WebSocket APIs can only be attached to a domain name with other WebSocket APIs. This must also occur through API Gateway's V2 DomainName interface.

I found out that using the resource `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping` instead of `AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping` fixes this issue, so I replaced this:

```
  PathMapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Properties:
      BasePath: '(none)'
      DomainName: !Ref CustomDomainName
      RestApiId: !Ref WebSocketApi
      Stage: !Ref Stage
```

with this:

```
  PathMappingV2:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref WebSocketApi
      DomainName: !Ref CustomDomainName
      Stage: !Ref Stage
```

Unfortunately, I've started getting this error:

> ApiMapping key already exists for this domain name.

Is there a proper way to solve this? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Currently solved by running Terraform apply twice. Once with the old section (PathMapping) removed and the new one commented (PathMappingV2) out - this removes the mapping. Then uncommenting the new section and applying again to recreate the mapping.